# Long Name Issues. Truncated on W2-C Form and Social Security card. How will it impact my Taxes and what should I know. (Full Issue in Description)

Tags: united-states, income-tax

This is my first time filing taxes in US. I have a long name on my Indian Passport. But here in USA, it cannot fit in properly on my Social Security card (my last name misses a space between two words, making it appear as one big word). My W2-C form misses lot of characters (at the end) from both my first name and last name.

All I want to know is if it will impact my Tax Filing/Returns?

Answer (score 4):

This will not affect your tax filing/returns in any way, since the matching is done by the SSN, not the name.

Comment: That response brings me some relief. I am wondering, why not just increase the character count on these fields? This problem is very intricate. TurboTax does not calculate the refund correctly, either. What a pain this is. What bothers me a lot is that the name on SSN is also not perfect (inline with my passport). Thank you anyway!

Comment: The IRS and SSA actually do perform name-matching to catch SSN/EIN data-entry errors as well as outright fraud. There can be penalties for providing an incorrect TIN ([Pub 1586](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p1586.pdf) mentions some, although it's aimed at 1099 payers, not W-2 payees). However, the automated matching for certain e-file processes only considers the fist four characters of a name, and if a name is obviously truncated I'm sure it would pass human review.